# Converting from binary to IEEE floating-point

Tags: binary, floating-point, ieee-754, exponent

I need to convert the binary number  0000 0110 1101 1001 1111 1110 1101 0011 to IEEE floating-point. The answer is 1.10110011111111011010011 x 2^−114, but how is the exponent derived?

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format

Take the first 9 digits

```
0 00001101
```

The first one is the sign (0 == positive)

The next 8 are the exponent, converted to decimal == 13. The sign in IEEE 32 binary float are offsetted by 127, so 13 - 127 = -114.

(and the missing 1 for the fraction part, it's implicit)

Done :-)

Answer (score 2):

for example  33.1 number

first:

convert decimal to binary

33.1 = 100001.0001100110011001100 . . .

second :

1.000010001100110011001100...*2^5

than :

Sing = positive = 0

Exponent = 5 + 127 = 132 = (1000100)

Mantissa = 000010001100110011001100...

S E M =0 1000100 000010001100110011001100 = (33.1)Decimal = (42046666)Hex

Answer (score 1):

Let's break the representation of your number up into the component parts of an IEEE-754 floating-point value:

```
   0 00001101 10110011111111011010011
sign exponent significand
```

The exponent field is `b00001101`, which is 13.  How do we get from there to -114?

The exponent of an IEEE-754 number is stored in a *biased* representation, which means that a fixed value is added to the true exponent to get the value stored in the encoding.  For single (32-bit) precision, the bias is 127.  To get the exponent from the encoding, we need to subtract off this bias:

```
13 - 127 = -114
```

the units bit of the significand is not stored (it is implicitly 1 unless the exponent field is zero), so we insert that bit into the significand, and get the value you listed:

```
b1.10110011111111011010011 * 2^-114
```